# JS. Использование массива как ключа в объекте

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, строки, объекты

Недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой. Для определённого набора идентификаторов я генерирую данные и хочу сохранить их в кэше. То есть грубо говоря хочу создать объект, в котором в качестве ключа мне нужен массив индентификаторов, а в качестве значения будут мои данные. Однако, как известно, стандартные объекты JS не позволяют иметь в качестве ключа ничего кроме `string`. Поэтому имеется задача по созданию уникального ключа из идентификаторов массива. Причём надо учитывать, что идентификаторы в массиве могут располагаться в различной последовательности, поэтому обычный `.join(',')` не поможет в такой ситуации. Распишу нагляднее, что мне надо

```
const cache = {};

const ids1 = ['1', '2', '3'];
const data1 = generateData(ids1);

const key1 = createKey(ids1) // ???????????????

cache[key1] = data1;

const ids2 = ['1', '3', '2']; // те же самые id, что и в ids1, но в другой последовательности
const key2 = createKey(ids2);

const data2 = cache[key2] || generateData(ids2); // data2 должна браться из кэша, поскольку генерировалась для одних и тех же ID, что и в первом случае
```

Задача сводится к написанию функцию `createKey(ids)`. Помогите

Comment: Так отсортируйте перед джоином

Answer (score 0):

Для сохранение объектов как ключей, вы можете использовать `Map` или `WeakMap`.

К сожалению, вашу проблему это на 100% не решит)

```js
const cache = new WeakMap();

const ids1 = ['1', '2', '3'];
const data1 = {
  x: 1
};
cache.set(ids1, data1);

const ids2 = ['1', '3', '2']; // те же самые id, что и в ids1, но в другой последовательности
const data2 = {
  x: 2
};

cache.set(ids2, data2);

console.log(cache.get(ids1))
console.log(cache.get(ids2))
```

Comment: да-да, именно поэтому я использую стандартный объект, а не Map или WeakMap, они не могут решать вопросы с последовательностью

Comment: @NickLaptev Ну так у вас в заголовке что написано? *Использование массива как ключа в объекте* - пожалуйста, можете использовать :) Тут еще вопрос в том, как у вас генерируются эти массивы id. Может, при генерации проверять, если есть уже такие.